# Is matrix norm the trace of its exponent?

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces

I have been trying to read the following paper : https://arxiv.org/pdf/1704.03864.pdf

In page $15$ of the pdf file, they have an inequality marked as $(10)$ which has been obtained using (I believe): $$||A||_p=tr[\exp(p.A)]^\frac{1}{p}$$

Is that true? And if true why is this true?

Comment: A hint:  do you remember definitions of $\lVert\cdot\rVert_p$ and $\lVert\cdot\rVert_1$? Apply them to both sides of display (10) in the paper.

Comment: @user539887 They are defined as the supremum over the ratios of norms of the vectors $Ax$ and $x$ in the vector norm. Do you want me to apply them on the matrices written inside the exponent?

Comment: I mean **vector** norms, not operator norms.

Comment: Sorry, but $A$ is a matrix and I am not sure what you want me to check because that statement gives real numbers from the matrix norms and gives the inequality.

Comment: Look at the RHS: $\mathrm{tr}$ is the sum of real numbers, and, since they are exponentials, they must be positive.

Comment: @user539887 Wow man you are a genius. Thanks. I don't know now whether I should delete this question.